# General Data Modeling overview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have been really deep thinking about a general way of creating "data model", and been jiggling with best practices and MVC pattern. Currently I am using a singleton pattern to get my httprequest and json parser (which comes as NSDictionary). Now rather than accessing this parser directly, I was hoping to make a Data model that can be binded through this.

However, I have been struggling if there is an easy way to do that rather than assigning manually "**[myObj setValue:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"name"]]**;" where myObj tends to be a simple NSString object.

Since NSDictionary is a nice KVC concept, how can I utilize this to enrich a better style of data model in which I can generally access myObj.name or myObj.address entity than "**[myObj setValue:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"name"]]**;" behavior.

I have looked into "Core Data" model, however the current design doesn't require to store anything locally, but just within memory for security reasons.

Any good ideas or best practices solution here will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your classes. Then crate an class that will serialize the data from your dictionaries to your object.

Let say you create an class Person that has properties firstName and lastName. Then you crate a Class like PresonController, that will do manage the person objects, and in it create class methods like

`+(Preson *)personFromDictionary:(NSDictionary)peseonDictionary;`

And every time you need to create an person from an dictionary you will do

```
Person *newPerson = [PersonController personFromDictionary:yourPersonDictionary];
```

And then in the code you just access the properties of the Person object

```
NSLog(@"Person first name:%@",newPerson.firstName);
```

Hope I was clear enough for you.

Comment: Terente, thanks for your input, this really makes a lot of sense now, I am just curious do I really need another class for PersonController or could I just replicate the method within Person Class? Also, this is a one way assignment, is order to update "parser object", I will again have to do the opposite right?